# Number of splits in a MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am creating a simple MapReduce job and I'd like to understand exactly the number of splits I have. I am running it locally.

There were 9 files in the folder. When no parameter, I got a lot of splits (172) I guess because of the host file system block size so I explicitly set

```
jobConf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize", "134217728");
```

And for my 9 files, I got 46 splits but I was expecting 47.

So I isolated the "problematic" file whose  size is (according to ls -al): 672067796

As per my calculation (total file size)/(min split size) for my isolated file = 672067796/134217728=5.007 (which means more than 5) so I should have got 6 splits but I have only 5

```
2016-08-12 16:02:34,391 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(198)) - number of splits:5
```

Can someone explain why? Is this something related to the host filesystem block size as well?

Regards

Comment: what is the file size of individual file size?

Comment: @Vishrant: Maybe was not clear, I am now running the job on only one file: the one for which there is a difference between the number of splits I thought and the actual number of splits. The size of this unique file according to 'ls -al' is 672067796

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Hadoop 2, as block size you specified is 128MB/ 134217728. In this case if your file size if 672067796 which means there should be 6 block. 5 block each of size 128MB where as last block will contain data of size ~7.47KB.

Explanation: The blocks are divided based on the size you have specified in the configuration otherwise it will take default value of 64MB or 128MB (based on hadoop version).

> 134217728/ 1024 / 1024 ~= 640.933MB
>
> 640.933 / 128 ~= 5.00729 blocks
>
> **this is not exactly 5 or less than 5** so for the remaining ~0.00729MB size of data a new block will be created.
>
> If you are using hadoop 0.x or 1.x you can do the above calculation with 64MB if you have *not specified the block size* on the configuration file.

Comment: This is exactly the calculus I made so I came to 6 blocks just like you. However, MapReduce output keeps saying that there are only 5 splits (see log output). "2016-08-12 16:02:34,391 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter (JobSubmitter.java:submitJobInternal(198)) - number of splits:5" So I still don't understand the gap between the two.